# WPF datagrid simple problem

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF `DataGrid` with a data source of `DataTable`. This `DataGrid` has just one column that is not `ReadOnly` where the user must enter data. How i can get values?

This is how i bind the data to the grid.

```
ConstructTable();

foreach (CheckOutData col in _CheckOutCollection)
{
    decimal paidMoney = 0;
    if (col.PaidMoney <= 0)
    {
        paidMoney = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        paidMoney = col.PaidMoney;
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(
        col.ID.ToString(),
        col.RoomType.ToString(),
        col.RoomNumber.ToString(),
        col.RoomPriceWithCurrency.ToString(),
        col.Discount.ToString(),
        col.DiscountedPriceWithCurrency.ToString(),
        col.CheckIn.ToString(),
        col.CheckOut.ToString(),
        col.TotalDay.ToString(),
        col.TotalPrice.ToString(),
        col.IncFirstDay.ToString(),
        paidMoney.ToString());

    _CheckInsIDs.Add(col.ID);
}

dataGrid1.DataContext = ds.Tables[0];
```

I'm selecting data from an SQL Table int a `Collection` `col`. As above, this `Collection` is used to populate the `DataTable`. 
i dont use more this _CheckOutCollection

Comment: You're gonna need to show some code or explain further how you bind data to your view, but you're looking for a TwoWay databinding.

Comment: i edited my question please see it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use two way mode in your datagrid column binding like below :

```
Binding="{Binding ColName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```